# How do I import a module with type in nodejs 16?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

So, I am using Node16/Typescript and am trying to import `discord.js`.

I would like to use `import` syntax, and not the `require` since I am more used to it, and also cause TS automatically add the types of what I import.

But sadly, it's such a mess, and there is so many import/require syntax that I never know what to do.

So I did this :

```
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import { Client, Intents } from 'discord.js';
```

with the simple tsconfig

```
        "target": "es2020"
        "module": "es2020" 
        "moduleResolution": "node"
```

but when I run my code it fail.

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'minLength')
> at file:///C:/Users/xxxx/Documents/Repository/xxxx/node_modules/@discordjs/builders/dist/index.mjs:1:831
> at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:185:25)
> at async Promise.all (index 0)
> at async ESMLoader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:281:24)
> at async loadESM (node:internal/process/esm_loader:88:5)
> at async handleMainPromise (node:internal/modules/run_main:65:12)

I know `discord.js` is exported as commonJs so I used `require` instead.

Now the code works, but the type are not found for what I import, and eslint complain of

> Require statement not part of import statement.

I tried all the other import / require solution but still nothing works, either it require `type : module` in package.json but the code won't work, either ts complain about how I import things...

basically if I use the way I want
`import { Client, Intents } from 'discord.js';` the code don7t work but the compiler and VsCode autocomplete everything and know the type (and eslint have no error)

`const Discord = require('discord.js');` will have no types, eslint will complain but the code will work...

what should I do ?

Answer (score 0):

target means that typescript is compiled to that target. Usually we use es2015 for this purpose to maximize supported platforms.
What you want is `lib`.

```
"target": "es2015",
"lib": ["es2020"]
```

Answer (score -2):

There is a problem with your `tsconfig.json`. 
It should be:

```json
"target": "es2015"
```

After changing this, run `tsc -p tsconfig.json` again.

Comment: Sorry, why I couldn't be targeting es2020 ? Does node wouldn't work with it ?

Comment: does it work after you changed it?